# Need clarification on conditional

Tags: differences, conditionals, subjunctive-mood

Are these two sentences grammatically correct and mean exactly the same?

> 1. If I knew he was going to come, I would have gone and met him.
> 2. If I had known he would come, I would have gone and met him.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct sentences, and their meaning is almost identical in this context. In (2) the knowledge is explicitly placed at the time, but in (1) the knowledge is placed at the time by implication.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that the first one is wrong, not because of the conditional 'if', but because of the time constraint. You would need to HAVE KNOWN in advance in order to go and meet him.

Comment: Thank you and of course, as you said, I should have known in advance that he would come.

Comment: @Akram please accept this answer using the green checkmark if it answers your question well enough